# Python NLTK: What's the difference between total entropy and per-word entropy?

Tags: python, nltk, entropy, cross-entropy

I'm required to find both the total cross entropy and per-word cross entropy of a given text using NLTK.

Specifically I'm using the entropy function here...
http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html

...but I'm unsure whether this calculates the total or per-word cross entropy and how to calculate the other one.

Can anyone offer me some insight?

Comment: Note that the NLTK implementation of entropy in the ngram module is "cross-entropy" not a single event entropy.